# creating user and sshkey with ansible user module

Tags: ansible-playbook

I wanna create some local and remote users and generate ssh keypair for respective users and transfer them to remote server but it seems local user - ansible - which runs ansible-playbook does not have access to /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

```
TASK [copy ssh key to destination users] ***************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ansible/project1/setup-user.yaml:21
Read vars_file 'vars/users.yaml'
Read vars_file 'vars/groups.yaml'
[WARNING]: Unable to find '/home/zahr1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)
File lookup using None as file
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: /home/zahr1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
}
[WARNING]: Unable to find '/home/zahr1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)
File lookup using None as file
fatal: [ansible1]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: /home/zahr1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
}
```

I'd appreciate if you let me know the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the public key directly into your playbook. For example:

```
- name: Set authorized key
  ansible.posix.authorized_key:
    user: zahr1
    state: present
    key: "ssh-ed25519 AAAAA.....0 zahr1@localhost"
```

You can also specify multiple keys.

```
- name: Set authorized key
  ansible.posix.authorized_key:
    user: zahr1
    state: present
    key: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - "ssh-ed25519 AAAAA.....1 zahr1@localhost"
    - "ssh-rsa AAAAA.....2 zahr1@localhost"
    - "ssh-dsa AAAAA.....3 zahr1@localhost"
```

Note that `ansible.posix.authorized_key` is for Ansible 2.10 and later (see its [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/authorized_key_module.html) as it must be installed separately with `ansible-galaxy`). Older versions of Ansible will use the now-deprecated `authorized_key`.

Comment: Thank you but I need to do the procedure automatically, copy the key from file manually is not the thing that I want.

Comment: @AlirezaNasri You said that Ansible does not have access to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Ansible authorized_key seems to not use the become_user, so does not have access to the .ssh folder of the user.
Solution: copy the `<user>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file to a `/tmp` location (as root/become_user) and then use authorized_keys to lookup in the /tmp folder.
Below adhoc commands to do the job. In a playboook add a task with the copy module.
(first `export PASS=mysecret` unless you want to replace the `-e` extra parameter with `-k` and type 5 times the password)

create the new user first on the ansible control host and generate new ssh keys

```
ansible localhost -m user -a "name=${a_new_user} generate_ssh_key=true"  \
-b -e "ansible_become_pass=${PASS}"
```

create this user also on all the hosts

```
ansible all -m user -a "name=${a_new_user}" -b -e  \
"ansible_become_pass=${PASS}"
```

copy the just created public key to a location that is accessable by the authorized_key command

```
sudo cp -p /home/${a_new_user}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /tmp/
```

now authorized_key can add the public key on all the hosts in the authorized_key file , but now lookup in the /tmp folder

```
ansible all -m authorized_key -a "user=${a_new_user} \
key={{ lookup('file', '/tmp/id_rsa.pub') }}" -b \
-e "ansible_user_passwd=${PASS}"
```

make sure the newly added user can sudo without password

```
ansible all -m lineinfile -a "path=/etc/sudoers state=present \
line='${a_new_user} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' \
validate='/usr/sbin/visudo -cf %s'" -b \
-e "ansible_become_pass=${PASS}"
```